# Getting error while Running 'perf c2c report -c pid,tid,iaddr,dso'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

While running 'perf c2c report -c pid,tid,iaddr,dso' command getting below error message.

```
Running 'perf c2c report -c pid,tid,iaddr,dso'
failed to open perf.data: No such file or directory  (try 'perf record' first)
```

Comment: So, do  you have perf.data ?

Comment: No, perf c2c record command was failing to create the perf.data file. It got resolved.